# Is the data on Google Nearline and Coldline redundantly stored?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

Google [mentions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/archival/) an average durability of  99.999999999% for Nearline and Coldline archival solutions. It does not mention about the geo-redundantly of the data. Is the data redundantly stored at multiple facilities? If yes, is the redundancy greater or less than the 'Regional' or 'Multi-Regional' class? Sorry, if this information is mentioned somewhere in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look on the [Storage Classes](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/storage-classes) page, it says:

> All storage classes support:
>
> - Redundant storage. Cloud Storage is designed for 99.999999999% durability.